# MySQL Deadlock Problems (PHP/MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, database-deadlocks

I have a section of code that is getting dead lock errors from MySQL.  Basically, I am doing a select to get a field, depending on that field I either increment a counter on that same record, or insert another.  This code is being called by several other systems.

Here is some clippings of what I am doing: (PHP/ZendFramework/MySQL)

```
$db = $dbMgr->GetConnection(); // gets a connection & starts transaction

// get a count field from the database...
$result = $db->query("SELECT status_id,status,count FROM status WHERE company_id={$companyId} AND probe_id={$probeId} AND host_id={$hostId} ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1;");

// do some stuff with the data.. maybe there is no current record, modify to use insert logic below

// only process if we have a command
if ($newStatus != $lastStatus) {
    $record = array();
    $record["status"] = $newStatus;
    $record["count"] = 1;
    $db->insert('status', $record); // INSERT THE RECORD
    $statusId = $db->lastInsertId();
} else {
    $db->query("UPDATE status SET count=count+1,last_updated=".time()." WHERE status_id={$lastRecord} LIMIT 1;"); // UPDATE THE RECORD
    $statusId = $lastRecord;
}

$dbMgr->commit(); // commits on success, rolls back on failure
```

[Edit] Thought that this may help:

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
120121 16:12:02
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION A42EF1D, ACTIVE 0 sec, process no 30952, OS thread id 1234467136 starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 3 lock struct(s), heap size 1248, 39 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 77901288, query id 705153914 ip-10-36-78-178.ec2.internal 10.36.78.178 root Sending data
SELECT qid,command,content_url,nextrundate,locked_until,data FROM items WHERE command='NOTIFY' AND status='PENDING' AND nextrundate <= 1327162322 AND 1327162322 > locked_until ORDER BY nextrundate  LIMIT 150 FOR UPDATE
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 404 page no 1223 n bits 232 index `PRIMARY` of table `queue`.`items` trx id A42EF1D lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 159 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 12; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 8; hex 00000000006fe5c4; asc      o  ;;
 1: len 6; hex 00000a42ef1a; asc    B  ;;
 2: len 7; hex 00000000390110; asc     9  ;;
 3: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 4: len 11; hex 50524f42455f4556454e54; asc PROBE_EVENT;;
 5: len 15; hex 352f3934302f3934302e70726f6265; asc 5/940/940.probe;;
 6: len 15; hex 50524f42455f4556454e545f393430; asc PROBE_EVENT_940;;
 7: len 4; hex 4f1ae3d1; asc O   ;;
 8: len 8; hex 434f4d504c455445; asc COMPLETE;;
 9: len 4; hex 4f1ae40d; asc O   ;;
 10: len 4; hex 4f1ae3d1; asc O   ;;
 11: len 0; hex ; asc ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION A42EF1A, ACTIVE 0 sec, process no 30952, OS thread id 1241389376 updating or deleting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
4 lock struct(s), heap size 1248, 11 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 77901285, query id 705153899 ip-10-190-211-216.ec2.internal 10.190.211.216 root updating
DELETE FROM items where status = 'DELETED' OR status = 'COMPLETE' LIMIT 2500
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 404 page no 1223 n bits 232 index `PRIMARY` of table `queue`.`items` trx id A42EF1A lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 159 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 12; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 8; hex 00000000006fe5c4; asc      o  ;;
 1: len 6; hex 00000a42ef1a; asc    B  ;;
 2: len 7; hex 00000000390110; asc     9  ;;
 3: len 1; hex 81; asc  ;;
 4: len 11; hex 50524f42455f4556454e54; asc PROBE_EVENT;;
 5: len 15; hex 352f3934302f3934302e70726f6265; asc 5/940/940.probe;;
 6: len 15; hex 50524f42455f4556454e545f393430; asc PROBE_EVENT_940;;
 7: len 4; hex 4f1ae3d1; asc O   ;;
 8: len 8; hex 434f4d504c455445; asc COMPLETE;;
 9: len 4; hex 4f1ae40d; asc O   ;;
 10: len 4; hex 4f1ae3d1; asc O   ;;
 11: len 0; hex ; asc ;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 404 page no 11287 n bits 280 index `comm.stat.next.locked` of table `queue`.`items` trx id A42EF1A lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 181 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 11; hex 50524f42455f4556454e54; asc PROBE_EVENT;;
 1: len 8; hex 434f4d504c455445; asc COMPLETE;;
 2: len 4; hex 4f1ae3d1; asc O   ;;
 3: len 4; hex 4f1ae40d; asc O   ;;
 4: len 8; hex 00000000006fe5c4; asc      o  ;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter A42F0C1
Purge done for trx's n:o < A42EF2E undo n:o < 0
History list length 117
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 0, not started, process no 30952, OS thread id 1241389376
MySQL thread id 77901343, query id 705156010 ip-10-85-61-62.ec2.internal 10.85.61.62 root
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
---TRANSACTION A2A4783, not started, process no 30952, OS thread id 1100028224
MySQL thread id 1, query id 705153376 localhost 127.0.0.1 rdsadmin
```

Comment: Saw someones comment on another similar question "InnoDB has problem with concurrent writes, especially if You insert data in the end of innodb table. "  - how are people dealing with this?

Comment: The deadlock report doesn't match the SQL you posted.  It's reporting deadlocks on a different table called "items".

Comment: I'll see if I can capture more accurate data

Comment: How long does it take to execute that SELECT statement from command line/phpmyadmin? Can it be executed at all?

Answer (score 0):

After digging deeper, the problem surfaced... there was another select in another program that was not using a key on the explain.. things look better.